# Why can't we input a vector as we input an array in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

The **wiki** says:
The elements of a vector are stored contiguously. AND
Vectors allow random access; that is, an element of a vector may be referenced in the same manner as elements of arrays (by array indices).

So why can't we input the elements of a vector as:

```
vector<int> v;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    cin>>v[i];
}
```

Comment: If you give the `vector` a *size*, yes. Otherwise it starts with 0 elements. If you have a fixed size, you can use `std::array` instead. But what is wrong with `push_back`?

Comment: @crashmstr given the number of questions on here about it I would add the caveat that if you have a fixed size *and that size can fit on the stack* you can use `std::array` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vector has zero elements right now. Try allocating it some space as:

```
vector<int> v(5);
```

Then your method would work.

Answer (score 4):

Either you need to resize the vector upfront - as other answers say - or you can use C++ standard library. Then the equivalent of your `for` loop is the following one line:

```
copy_n(istream_iterator<int>(cin), 3, back_inserter(v));
```

and it takes care of allocation/resizing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you need to allocate the elements of the vector first. So try `vector<int> v(4);`, so it will start with 4 elements. Then you can load values into them.